# How to run docker image in GitHub action with npm command

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to run a docker container in github action with npm command.

```
  - name: Run docker container
    env:
      BRANCH_TAG: ${{needs.test.outputs.BRANCH}}
      ENV: ${{needs.test.outputs.ENV}}
    run: |
      docker run -it -e ENV=$ENV \
        12xxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/test/app:$BRANCH_TAG \
        -- sh -c "npm run app:test:quest"
```

When I run `docker run` command with `-it`. I get `the input device is not a TTY` error.

When I use `-i` or without `-i`. I am getting this error `tail: invalid number of bytes: 'npm run cy:test:parallel:github'`

and if I use `-d` then I am not getting any logs generating from the npm command. How to run docker container which will show the npm logs as well?